# How do I avoid duplicate entries while selecting data from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables student, education, visits, medical data. I am trying to create something like advanced search form where user can enter criteria. from Student table I am fetching  student's name, phone, address etc. from education I am getting group, department and create and university name. from visits I am trying to get speciallistApointmant there could be more then one of them. Tables are related using bridge tables student_to_visit, student_to_education and medicaldata_to_student

Here is the sql query I am currently using

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  s.ID,
  m.vision,
  m.hearing,
  m.movement,
  m.cardno,
  v.speciallistApointmant,
  s.fio,
  s.birthdate,
  edge,
  gender,
  homeaddress,
  actualaddress,
  phone,
  workplace,
  enterence,
  financesource,
  studyform,
  c.gruppa,
  c.greate,
  c.departmant
FROM
  student s,
  education_to_student b,
  education c,
  student_to_visit sv,
  visits v,
  medicaldata_to_student ms,
  medicaldata m
where
  b.student_id = s.id
  and b.education_id = c.id
  and ms.student_id=s.id
  and ms.medical_id=m.id
  and sv.student_id=s.id
  and sv.visit_id=v.id
  and gender = 1
```

Since because one student can visit more then one specialist students are shown more then once. Also if there are no visits for particular student that student doesn't appear in query result. In example above I tried to select students with gender=1 but there is a possibility of more parameters. How to build this query correctly?

Here is PHP code with form:

```
public function getstats($gender,$greate,$edge,$financesource,$birthdate,$hearing,$vision,$movement,$cardno,$speciallistApointmant)
    {
       //where begin

       $where=" where b.student_id = s.id and b.education_id = c.id and ms.student_id=s.id and ms.medical_id=m.id and sv.student_id=s.id and sv.visit_id=v.id";
    // echo var_dump($gender);
       if ($gender!='')
       {
           echo var_dump($gender);
           $where .=" and gender = $gender";
   //  echo var_dump($gender);
       }
           if (!empty($greate))
           {
               $where .="and greate='$greate'";
       }
     if (!empty($edge))  
     {
         $where .="and edge='$edge' ";
     }
     if (!empty($financesource))
     {
         $where .="and financesource='$financesource'";
     }
     //birthdate add here


     //end
     if (!empty($hearing))
     {
         $where.="and hearing='$hearing";
     }
     if (!empty($vision))
     {
         $where .="and vision='$vision'";
     }
       if (!empty($movement))
       {
           $where .="and movement='$movement'";
       }
       if (!empty($cardno))
       {
           $where.="and cardno='$cardno'";
       }
       if (!empty($speciallistApointmant))
       {
           $where .="and speciallistApointmant='$speciallistApointmant'";
       }
       //echo var_dump($where);
       //where end

       $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT s.ID, m.vision, m.hearing, m.movement, m.cardno,v.speciallistApointmant, s.fio, s.birthdate, edge, gender, homeaddress, actualaddress, phone, workplace, enterence, financesource, studyform, c.gruppa, c.greate, c.departmant\n"
    . "FROM student s, education_to_student b, education c,student_to_visit sv, visits v,medicaldata_to_student ms, medicaldata m"."$where";
```

Comment: Please always take the time to format your code so that it is readable at a glance, with minimal scrolling - especially horizontally.

Comment: If a student visits more than one specialist but you want to return just one row per student, how would you want decide which specialist visit to return?

Comment: Basicly I have to return only specillist that was specified in the php form otherways I don't even need to select one

Comment: I have added the php code that forms the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT uses all the fields listed to determine if a row is distinct or not, because you use all the education, visits, and medicaldata fields in your select, you get duplicate students with distinct visits (or similar for other tables).

If you need the other table data in your query (not just student data) look into GROUP BY and use aggregate functions (count, min, max, etc) for your other table fields.

If you just need a list of students, remove the other table columns from your SELECT phrase. You can use columns in a WHERE phrase even if they are not in the SELECT phrase.

Also: you should really be using [PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) (or other DB layer) and Preparing your queries to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

> Also if there are no visits for particular student that student doesn't appear in query result.

You can use **Left join** or **Right join** to retrieve orphans, that is data that are not related to a record in another table. for example

```
SELECT s.ID, s.name, m.vision, m.hearing FROM Student s LEFT JOIN medicaldata_to_student ms on s.id=md.student_id LEFT JOIN medicaldata m on ms.medical_id=m.id;
```

Will retrieve student data with related medical data. And if a student doesn't have medical data, his id and his name will be set and medical data will be set to null.